# regression with very low R2, metric coefficient interpretation

Tags: regression-coefficients

my regression model give extremely low R2. In this case can i still interpret my X variables with significant p-value in the way that x goes up by 1 unit, y goes up by coefficient unit (with others hold the same)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Your low $R^2$ just means that this prediction will be worse than if $R^2$ had been greater, but it will still be correct on average.

Comment: Thank you Stephan. How do i then tell one metric is more important than the other metric? the coefficient is bigger? or the P value for coefficient is smaller?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with your model. If you want to publish an academic article, smaller p values are unfortunately better. If you want to predict a response, the prediction error is more important.

Comment: Thank you Stephan, i might misunderstand your point. 'If you want to predict a response, the prediction error is more important.', by saying this, you meant R2 right?

Also, if two features in your model, one has coefficient 100, with p-value 0.01. The other has coefficient 10, but p value 0.001. If you are giving recommendations on most influential metric, which one you will suggest?

Comment: No. [$R^2$ is usually not used to assess predictive accuracy.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A1352+%5Br-squared%5D%5Bforecasting%5D) Better to use MSE, MAD, or something else - as long as it is consistent with your loss function, i.e., what you will use your prediction for and how much an error will hurt you.

Comment: Thank you again Stephan. :) just follow up on this part of the question. 
 if two features in your model, one has coefficient 100, with p-value 0.01. The other has coefficient 10, but p value 0.001. If you are giving recommendations on most influential metric, which one you will suggest?

Comment: It depends on the scale of the predictor. If the first one varies between 0 and 1, then its impact on the outcome varies between 0 and 100. If the second predictor varies between 0 and 1,000, then its impact will vary between 0 and 10,000. So the second one sounds more influential. This is something you can only decide by looking at your actual problem and at what your predictors are.